Flutter Firebase error "Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/v1/token</code> from this server." how to solve this
Hi i have flutter project and i use firebase Auth and Firestore with emulator.
when i open first time my app and login , all of things is ok but when i close the app and reopen this
i get error from Auth "Your client does not have permission to get URL /v1/token from this server." when i will refresh token and if i will not refresh token i get error from Auth "Your client does not have permission to get URL /identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo from this server."
If I don't pay attention to it, after opening and closing the program a few times, I will lose access to Firestore, and I must Logout and login again.
thanks for your help
I Searched Google and AIs but my problem not solved
